# Hive query with Map Data type fails

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have written the following hive query. Here I am trying to use a column (msg) of Map data type in my join clause.

```
select p.p_id, count(*) from prod_json n 
inner join res_pan p on n.msg["mid"] = p.id
where n.cat='XYX'
group by p.p_id limit 10;
```

This query always fails with error message

```
    [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONObject at 
org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.JsonMapObjectInspector.getMap(Json
MapObjectInspector.java:40) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:317) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:353) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:197) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:183) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.toErrorMessage(MapOperator.java:
529) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:502) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:170) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453) at
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve the problem. I re-wrote my query as

```
select t2.p_id, count(*)
from (select cat, msg["mid"] as mid from prod_json) t1
join (select id, p_id from res_pan) t2
on t1.mid = t2.id
where t1.cat = 'XYZ'
group by t2.p_id
```

So basically don't try to use the map column directly but first platten the map into columns by using inner queries and then join on those.